# Assigning SQL reader leaves code

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sqldatareader

I am having an issue with my c# code.  I am trying to check if a username exists already so I have a select statement but when I breakpoint it, it leaves the code right after I assign the reader.  Here is my code:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.CategoriesConnectionString);
SqlCommand chkUser = new SqlCommand("SELECT [Username] FROM [Accounts] WHERE [Username] = @username", conn);
chkUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", txtUsername.Text);
conn.Open();
SqlDataReader sqlReader = chkUser.ExecuteReader(); //leaves code right here


if (sqlReader.HasRows)
{
    MessageBox.Show("That username already exists.  Please choose another.");
    txtUsername.Focus();
    return;
}
conn.Close();
```

I figure it is because there is nothing in the table yet but I don't know why it is not checking whether or not it has rows and is just leaving.
Any help is appreciated.  Thanks

Comment: It sounds like you get an exception, that's the only reason why the execution would not continue with the next statement. Do you catch it somewhere?

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Answer (score 0):

Some more information on the issue would be useful. Seems like you are getting an exception for some reason (as @Guffa said) and without any further details it becomes difficult guessing what the reason is. Try changing the code you posted to the following:

```
using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.CategoriesConnectionString))
using(SqlCommand chkUser = new SqlCommand("SELECT [Username] FROM [Accounts] WHERE [Username] = @username", conn))
{
  chkUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", txtUsername.Text);

  try
  {
    conn.Open();

    using(SqlDataReader sqlReader = chkUser.ExecuteReader()) 
    {
      if (sqlReader.HasRows)
      {
        MessageBox.Show("That username already exists.  Please choose another.");
        txtUsername.Focus();
        return;
      }
    }
  }
  catch(Exception e)
  {
    // manage exception  
  }
}
```

and see if something changes. In case it doesn't try debugging and see what kind of exception it throws.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that i use in a login scenario where i've stored usernames in a mysql database table.
Even though i use MySQL there shouldnt be much of a difference.(not sure about this though).

```
public static string CheckUsername()
{
  bool usernameCheck = false;
  InitiateDatabase();//contains the root.Connection string

  MySqlCommand readCommand = rootConnection.CreateCommand();

  readCommand.CommandText = String.Format("SELECT username FROM `SCHEMA`.`USERTABLE`");

  rootConnection.Open();
  MySqlDataReader Reader = readCommand.ExecuteReader();

  while (Reader.Read())
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < Reader.FieldCount; i++)
    {
      if (Reader.GetValue(i).ToString() == USERNAME_STRING)
      {
        usernameCheck = true;
      }
    }
  }
  rootConnection.Close();

  if (usernameCheck)
  {
    return "Succes";
  }
  else
  {
    return "Wrong Username!";
  }
}
```

This is of course without exception handling, which you might find useful during testing and if its meant to be used by others.